# Why is 'Confirm Order' pane being skipped?

Tags: commerce

I’m trying to determine why the ‘Confirm Order’ pane is being skipped in my Drupal Commerce Kickstart website.

Configuring the checkout process is here.

admin/commerce/config/checkout

In the configuration settings i’ve set

‘Display this pane in a non-collapsible fieldset.’

i’ve also checked boxes of info to be displayed in the pane, such as Shipping service.

Anyone know why it is being skipped? and how to fix? this seems like a bug

Comment: Confirm Order seems like something custom - or was it just newly added ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checkout pane / page is added by the PayPal Express Checkout module. PayPal EC has a step where you return from PayPal after authorizing payment to finalize the order, including taxes, shipping selection, coupon entering, etc. For other payment methods, this page is skipped.